# Upgrading Subversive connectors in eclipse using the Connector Discovery

Tags: eclipse, subversive

I might be blind, but I can't seem to bring up the Subversive Connector Discovery dialog on an already set up Subversive in eclipse. I need to upgrade from an SVNKit that supports 1.6 to one that takes 1.7, but I just can't find a way to *add* connectors.
Thanks!

PS: this is an eclipse Juno related question

Comment: So far I went with the past of least resistance: uninstall and reinstall ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't get the discovery working, install them using the normal update manager with the [Juno Subversive connectors update site](http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/3.0/juno-site/).

Comment: Works the same for Kepler: `http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/3.0/kepler-site/`